# android how to select setOnItemClickListener to get proper value selected

Tags: android, android-volley

android on `setOnItemClickListener` not work properly how to selected values get 
show as ShareWithArticle@211f2370

```
To.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String selected = String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(position));

                        }
                    });
```

**my code**

```
    public class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShareWithArticle> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments;
    private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments_All;
    private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments_Suggestion;
    private final int mLayoutResourceId;

    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ShareWithArticle> departments) {
        super(context, resource, departments);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
        this.mDepartments = new ArrayList<>(departments);
        this.mDepartments_All = new ArrayList<>(departments);
        this.mDepartments_Suggestion = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mDepartments.size();
    }

    public ShareWithArticle getItem(int position) {
        return mDepartments.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }
            ShareWithArticle department = getItem(position);
            final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            final TextView userId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            name.setText(department.getUsrCompNm());
            userId.setText(department.getUsrID() + "");
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String userNm  =   name.getText().toString();
                    String userIdtxt = userId.getText().toString();

                   // userNm      how to pass values shareFragment
                    //userIdtxt     how to pass values shareFragment

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                return ((ShareWithArticle) resultValue).getUsrCompNm();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (constraint != null) {
                    mDepartments_Suggestion.clear();
                    for (ShareWithArticle department : mDepartments_All) {
                        if (department.getUsrCompNm().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            mDepartments_Suggestion.add(department);
                        }
                    }
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = mDepartments_Suggestion;
                    filterResults.count = mDepartments_Suggestion.size();
                    return filterResults;
                } else {
                    return new FilterResults();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mDepartments.clear();
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // avoids unchecked cast warning when using mDepartments.addAll((ArrayList<Department>) results.values);
                    List<?> result = (List<?>) results.values;
                    for (Object object : result) {
                        if (object instanceof ShareWithArticle) {
                            mDepartments.add((ShareWithArticle) object);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (constraint == null) {
                    // no filter, add entire original list back in
                    mDepartments.addAll(mDepartments_All);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

myFragment my dialogFragment

```
    public class ShareFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    TextView share;
    EditText message;
    AutoCompleteTextView To;
    Context context;
    String articleID;
    ArrayList<ShareWithArticle> userList = new ArrayList<>();


    CustomerAdapter adapter;
    public ShareFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.alert_dialog);
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        articleID = getArguments().getString("ArticleId");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String nms = bundle.getString("startFromWS");
        M.i("==============LS",""+nms);


    }

    public void postCompanyArticle(final String message, final String share) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ConfigApi.ShareArticle(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

              //  M.i("==================SHARE", "" + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String msg = VolleyException.getErrorMessageFromVolleyError(error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("content_id", articleID);
                params.put("content_type", "article");
                params.put("message", message);
                params.put("share_with", share);
                return params;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(3 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
            getDialog().setOnDismissListener(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share, container, false);
        share = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.overCmt);
        To = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.to);
        message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

        TextView cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.overLink);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String to = To.getText().toString();
                String msg = message.getText().toString();
                postCompanyArticle(msg,to);
            }
        });

        To.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                UserTo(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void UserTo(String share) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ConfigApi.UserToArticle(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //userList = ShareWithArticleJson.parseResponse(response);
                //adapter.setList(list);

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray(DATA);
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        ShareWithArticle ls = new ShareWithArticle();
                        JSONObject item = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = item.getString("UsrFNm");
                        int UsrID = item.getInt("UsrID");

                        ShareWithArticle ll =new  ShareWithArticle();
                        ll.setUsrCompNm(name);
                        ll.setUsrID(UsrID);
                        userList.add(ll);

                    }

                    final CustomerAdapter adapter = new CustomerAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_share_adapter , userList);
                    To.setAdapter(adapter);
                    To.setThreshold(1);

                    To.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String selected = String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(position));

                        }
                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String msg = VolleyException.getErrorMessageFromVolleyError(error);
            }
        });
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(3 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your adapter consists "ShareWithArticle" class's object. Instead of "String selected = String.valueOf(adapter.getItem(position));" use this --- > ShareWithArticle shareObj = (ShareWithArticle)adapter.getItem(position)

Comment: not working please other suggestion

Comment: please fix the question

Comment: what error or issue are you facing exactly? Please edit your question with the same. Also post your ShareWithArticle class's code

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView not close drop down show code second answers

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShareWithArticle> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments;
    private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments_All;
    private final List<ShareWithArticle> mDepartments_Suggestion;
    private final int mLayoutResourceId;
SharedFragment fragment;
    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ShareWithArticle> departments,SharedFragment fragment) {
        super(context, resource, departments);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutResourceId = resource;
        this.mDepartments = new ArrayList<>(departments);
        this.mDepartments_All = new ArrayList<>(departments);
        this.mDepartments_Suggestion = new ArrayList<>();

        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mDepartments.size();
    }

    public ShareWithArticle getItem(int position) {
        return mDepartments.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }
            ShareWithArticle department = getItem(position);
            final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            final TextView userId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            name.setText(department.getUsrCompNm());
            userId.setText(department.getUsrID() + "");
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new Listener(name,userId));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
class Listener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    TextView name;
     TextView userId;

    Listener(TextView name, TextView userId)
    {
    this.name = name;
    this.userId = userId;

    }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                           String userNm  =   name.getText().toString();
                    String userIdtxt = userId.getText().toString();

                    //create a method in fragment class and pass the data using tthe object.

                fragment.setData(userNm,userIdtxt);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                return ((ShareWithArticle) resultValue).getUsrCompNm();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (constraint != null) {
                    mDepartments_Suggestion.clear();
                    for (ShareWithArticle department : mDepartments_All) {
                        if (department.getUsrCompNm().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            mDepartments_Suggestion.add(department);
                        }
                    }
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = mDepartments_Suggestion;
                    filterResults.count = mDepartments_Suggestion.size();
                    return filterResults;
                } else {
                    return new FilterResults();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mDepartments.clear();
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // avoids unchecked cast warning when using mDepartments.addAll((ArrayList<Department>) results.values);
                    List<?> result = (List<?>) results.values;
                    for (Object object : result) {
                        if (object instanceof ShareWithArticle) {
                            mDepartments.add((ShareWithArticle) object);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (constraint == null) {
                    // no filter, add entire original list back in
                    mDepartments.addAll(mDepartments_All);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: fragment.setData(userNm,userIdtxt); how to use

Comment: create a method in ShowFragment Class

Comment: and pass the Same fragment object in Adapter also

Comment: thanks you  it's working but not close drop down menu

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView not close drop down

Comment: and not selected drop down text

Answer (score 0):

try to set tag for userID you are trying to set value on the layout & get the id from tag where you are capturing click. Inside getView method you can do this. No need to collect the item position in this case, you can directly get the item id. Refer to code for more details. I hope this may help you.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
try {  
if (convertView == null) {  
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();  
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);  
}  
ShareWithArticle department = getItem(position);  
final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
final TextView userId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);  
name.setText(department.getUsrCompNm());  
userId.setText(department.getUsrID() + "");  
userId.setTag("set your key here like layout id", department.getUsrID());  
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
    String userNm  =   name.getText().toString();  
    String userIdtxt = userId.getText().toString();  
    // userNm how to pass values shareFragment  
    //userIdtxt how to pass values shareFragment  
}});  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  
return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add method like this in your adapter class

```
public ShareWithArticle getItemAt(int position) {
    mDepartments.get(position);
}
```

now

```
To.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                               ShareWithArticle sa=adapter.getItemAt(position); 

                        }
                    });
```

Hope it will help you

Or

```
To.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
ShareWithArticle sa=(ShareWithArticle)adapter.getItem(position); 
                        }
                    });
```